# Using react-papaparse in the Next.js getStaticProps - XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Tags: next.js, papaparse, react-papaparse

I am trying to use [papaparse](https://www.papaparse.com) inside my Next.js page. I am using [react-papaparse](https://github.com/Bunlong/react-papaparse) package which is a React wrapper for Papaparse. I am trying to parse remote CSV file inside `getStaticProps()` function but the error I get is **XMLHttpRequest is not defined**.

I know that `getStaticProps()` is executed on Node.js but I don't know how to use react-paparse correctly to avoid XMLHttpRequest call. Here is my code:

```
// index.js Next.js page

import { usePapaParse } from "react-papaparse";

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { readRemoteFile } = usePapaParse();
  readRemoteFile(googleSheetUrl, {
    complete: (results) => {
      console.log("PAPAPARSE::complete", results)
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: You can't use React hooks inside `getStaticProps` (it's server-side code). Just use `papaparse` instead.